# My retrofit gson deserializer don't see enum

Tags: json, kotlin, enums, gson, retrofit2

Whenever I'm getting response from the server where JSON looks like that
`{"rights":[{"name":"stock_management","right":true}]}`
my retrofit uses class `SimpleResponse<T>` to convert it to my desired response but instead working as intended I'm getting emptylist as a value for rights.

```
data class SimpleResponse<T>(
    val data: T? = null,
    val error: String? = null,
    val rights: List<LMSPermission> = emptyList()
)

@Entity
data class LMSPermission(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
    val name: Permission,
    val right: Boolean = false
) {
    enum class Permission(val lmsName: String) {
        @SerializedName("stock_management")
        STOCK_PERMISSION("stock_management")
    }
}
```

I tried to just create gson instance and generate classes from that but everything worked fine so i tried to add interceptor to my retrofit instance and there I tried to get class instance from response and it worked.

```
@Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideRetrofitDAO(): RetrofitDao {
        val gson = GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(Event::class.java, EventDeserializer())

        val logging = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
            .setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)
        val httpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .addInterceptor(logging)
            .addInterceptor { chain ->
                val response = chain.proceed(chain.request().newBuilder().build())
                Log.d(TAG, "provideRetrofitDAO: $response")
                response.let {
                    if (it.code == 200)
                        Log.d(TAG, "provideRetrofitDAO: ${gson.create().fromJson<SimpleResponse<Any>>(it.body.string(), TypeToken.getParameterized(SimpleResponse::class.java, Any::class.java).type)}")
                }
                response
            }
        val retrofitBuilder =
            Retrofit
                .Builder()
                .baseUrl(if (MainActivity.debug) API_BASE_URL_DEBUG else API_BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(
                    GsonConverterFactory.create(gson.create())
                )
                .callbackExecutor(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor())
        val retrofit =
            retrofitBuilder
                .client(
                    httpClient.build()
                )
                .build()

        return retrofit.create(RetrofitDao::class.java)
    }
```

At this point I'm quite sure that  converter factory is at fault but I don't know how to repair that nor how to check if it is really a problem.

Comment: Have you tried to add @SerializedName annotation for LMSPermission data class and permission enum class ?

Comment: Is this an Android project, or are you using ProGuard / R8? In that case the field name `SimpleResponse.rights` might be obfuscated.

Comment: @Marcono1234 It is an Android project, also I don't use this name anywhere else in project so only way would be if one of my libraries would use it.

Comment: @AhmetBurakIlhan Yes I tried to add this and It didn't helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that writing my own GsonConverterFactory where I'm using `fromJson` method instead of adapter from `getAdapter` was the answer. Don't ask me why this works but here is the code, `MyTypeAdapter` is not really implemented because I used it as a container for `Type` variable.

```
class MyGsonConverterFactory(val gson: Gson) : Converter.Factory() {
        override fun responseBodyConverter(
            type: Type,
            annotations: Array<out Annotation>,
            retrofit: Retrofit
        ): Converter<ResponseBody, *> {
            val adapter = MyTypeAdapter<Any>(type)
            return GsonResponseBodyConverter(gson, adapter)
        }

        override fun requestBodyConverter(
            type: Type,
            parameterAnnotations: Array<Annotation?>,
            methodAnnotations: Array<Annotation?>,
            retrofit: Retrofit
        ): Converter<*, RequestBody> {
            val adapter = gson.getAdapter(TypeToken.get(type))
            return GsonRequestBodyConverter(gson, adapter)
        }
    }

    internal class GsonResponseBodyConverter<T>(
        private val gson: Gson,
        private val adapter: TypeAdapter<T>
    ) :
        Converter<ResponseBody, T> {
        @Throws(IOException::class)
        override fun convert(value: ResponseBody): T {
            (adapter as? MyTypeAdapter)?.typeToken!!.let {
                val test = gson.fromJson<T>(value.string(), it)
                Log.d(TAG, "convert: $test")
                return test
            }
        }
    }

    internal class GsonRequestBodyConverter<T>(
        private val gson: Gson,
        private val adapter: TypeAdapter<T>
    ) : Converter<T, RequestBody> {
        @Throws(IOException::class)
        override fun convert(value: T): RequestBody {
            val buffer = Buffer()
            val writer: Writer = OutputStreamWriter(buffer.outputStream(), UTF_8)
            val jsonWriter = gson.newJsonWriter(writer)
            adapter.write(jsonWriter, value)
            jsonWriter.close()
            return buffer.readByteString().toRequestBody(MEDIA_TYPE)
        }

        companion object {
            private val MEDIA_TYPE: MediaType = "application/json; charset=UTF-8".toMediaType()
            private val UTF_8 = Charset.forName("UTF-8")
        }
    }

    internal class MyTypeAdapter<T>(val typeToken: Type) : TypeAdapter<T>() {
        override fun write(out: JsonWriter?, value: T) {}
        override fun read(`in`: JsonReader?): T { TODO() }
    }
```